# Mysqldump geometry field error

Tags: mysqldump, mysql-8.0, geometry

I have MySQL 8 database with some tables that have some column of type GEOMETRY.

When I back up the table with mysqldump, it outputs my geometry column as `_binary '\æ\0\0\...` and when I try to restore the dump to fails with an error:

"Cannot get GEOMETRY object from the data you send to the Geometry field".

Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Have you tried using [--hex-blob](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob) in mysqldump ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha that seems to have resolved it. Many thanks.